# Best Tab option for Grails gsp

Tags: grails, tabs, gsp

What is the best option for tab component in gsp?

**Option 1 (JQuery)**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'tabcomponent', action: 'search')}">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'tabcomponent', action: 'result')}">Result</a></li>
     :
```

**Option 2 (JQuery)**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Search</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Result</a></li> 
       :

div id="tabs-1"
  <g:include controller="tabcomponent" action="search"/>
/div
<div id="tabs-2">
    <g:include controller="tabcomponent" action="result"/>
</div>
```

**Option 3 (RichUI Plugin)**

```
<resource:tabView />

<richui:tabView id="tabView">
    <richui:tabLabels>
        <richui:tabLabel selected="true" title="My Tab 1" />
     </richui:tabLabels>

    <richui:tabContents>
```

In Option 2 and 3, the tab (page) is not getting loaded dynamically ie., all tabs are loaded on page load, but tab-2 (result) needs to be loaded based on first tab action. Option 1 loads the page as expected but I wanted to know which is the best way to use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "best way" to work with tabs. Use the one that you're more familiar with and fit your needs.

JQuery UI also [have an option](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) to load tabs with ajax.